# Does teiid have a hash function such as md5?

Tags: redhat-datavirt

I need to compare two tables of changed records, in the past I have used md5 or other hash functions on concatenated records to compare. Is the a hash/md5 function available?

Answer (score 0):

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIID-4532 - md5 and sha functions are in both JDV and Teiid.  They are documented at http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/Security_Functions.html